# dimension extension with pytorch tensors

Tags: pytorch, gpu, tensor, dimensions

What is the way dimension extension with pytorch tensors?

-before:
torch.Size([3, 3, 3])

```
tensor([[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
         [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
         [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

        [[ 9., 10., 11.],
         [12., 13., 14.],
         [15., 16., 17.]],

        [[18., 19., 20.],
         [21., 22., 23.],
         [24., 25., 26.]]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
```

-after:
torch.Size([2, 3, 3, 3])

```
tensor([[[[ 0.,  1.,  2.],
          [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
          [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

         [[ 9., 10., 11.],
          [12., 13., 14.],
          [15., 16., 17.]],

         [[18., 19., 20.],
          [21., 22., 23.],
          [24., 25., 26.]]],


        [[[0., 1., 2.],
          [ 3.,  4.,  5.],
          [ 6.,  7.,  8.]],

         [[ 9., 10., 11.],
          [12., 13., 14.],
          [15., 16., 17.]],

         [[18., 19., 20.],
          [21., 22., 23.],
          [24., 25., 26.]]]], device='cuda:0', dtype=torch.float64)
```

under numpy would work like this:

```
b =  np.broadcast_to(a1[None, :,:,:], (2,3,3,3))
```

How does this work under pytorch? I want to take advantage of the gpu. Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new dimension can be added with `unsqeeze` (`0` used below to specify the first dimension, i.e., position `0`), followed by repeating the data twice along that dimension (and once, i.e., no repetitions, along the other dimensions).

```py
before = torch.tensor(..., dtype=torch.float64, device='cuda:0')
after = before.unsqueeze(0).repeat(2, 1, 1, 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use [`torch.Tensor.expand`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand) for your given expected results

```py
b = a1.expand([2, 3, 3, 3])
```